# How do I resolve "function get_xmlbinary() does not exist" errors in Heroku Connect?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-connect

I have tried SET search_path To public.

But it again throws the same errror function get_xmlbinary() does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way to resolve this issue, is to contact Heroku Support Team, They resolved this issue from their side.

Comment: Although the function is created by Heroku, this may not be their problem. One reason could be database search path has been changed so that the public schema is not in the search path.

Comment: I've contacted Heroku Support Team, They resolved this issue from their side. Thanks a lot